# Tkinter: How to stop MouseWheel from simultaneously scrolling scrollbars on separate Notebook tabs

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm playing around with the scrollbar and the ttk.Notebook functions to create two scrollable tabs.  I have the mousewheel bound to scrolling, but it always scrolls both tabs.  When you first run the code, you can scroll the first tab by itself because the second tab hasn't been "activated" for lack of a better term.  Once you click the second tab to view it, all further scrolling on either tab scrolls both tabs evenly.  The scrollbars do work independently when scrolled manually.

Is there a way to only bind the mousewheel to the selected tab at any one time?

Edit: I've noticed another weird behavior that if you resize the window outward everything reacts as it should, but if you resize the window making it narrower, the scrollbar disappears to the right of the now narrower window.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

Window = Tk()

# Create the Outer Frame
outer_frame = Frame(Window)
outer_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

# Create and add the tabs
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(outer_frame)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab1, text="Tab 1")
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab2, text="Tab 2")
tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

# Create the canvases
canvas1 = Canvas(tab1)
canvas1.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)
canvas2 = Canvas(tab2)
canvas2.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=1)

# Add scrollbars to canvases
scrollbar1 = ttk.Scrollbar(tab1, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas1.yview)
scrollbar1.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
scrollbar2 = ttk.Scrollbar(tab2, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas2.yview)
scrollbar2.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

def _on_mousewheel(event):
    canvas1.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")
    canvas2.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")

# Bind mousewheel to scrollbars
canvas1.bind("<MouseWheel>", _on_mousewheel)
canvas2.bind("<MouseWheel>", _on_mousewheel)

# Configure the canvases scrollbars
canvas1.configure(scrollregion=canvas1.bbox('all'), yscrollcommand=scrollbar1.set)
canvas1.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas1.configure(scrollregion = canvas1.bbox("all")))
canvas2.configure(scrollregion=canvas2.bbox('all'), yscrollcommand=scrollbar2.set)
canvas2.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas2.configure(scrollregion = canvas2.bbox("all")))

# Create frames inside the canvases
inner_frame1 = ttk.Frame(canvas1)
inner_frame2 = ttk.Frame(canvas2)

# Add the frames to the canvases
canvas1.create_window((0,0), window=inner_frame1, anchor="nw")
canvas2.create_window((0,0), window=inner_frame2, anchor="nw")

# Add buttons to the frames
for thing in range(20):
    ttk.Button(inner_frame1, text=f'Button {thing}').grid(row=thing, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)
    ttk.Button(inner_frame2, text=f'Button {thing}').grid(row=thing, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)

Window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It looks like you're explicitly configuring it to scroll two canvases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the function to this:

```py
def _on_mousewheel(event):
    event.widget.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")
```

It find the canvas that caught the event and changes its `yview_scroll`.

I also solved the second problem but I still don't know why exactly. Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53340201/11106801) answer I figured out what works and a plausible explanation for it. You have to move your `canvas.pack(...)` statements after you have packed the scroll bar. So your code should look like this:

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

Window = Tk()

# Create the Outer Frame
outer_frame = Frame(Window)
outer_frame.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

# Create and add the tabs
tab_control = ttk.Notebook(outer_frame)
tab1 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab1, text="Tab 1")
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tab_control)
tab_control.add(tab2, text="Tab 2")
tab_control.pack(expand=1, fill=BOTH)

# Create the canvases
canvas1 = Canvas(tab1, bg="orange")
canvas2 = Canvas(tab2, bg="light blue")

# Add scrollbars to canvases
scrollbar1 = ttk.Scrollbar(tab1, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas1.yview)
scrollbar1.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
scrollbar2 = ttk.Scrollbar(tab2, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas2.yview)
scrollbar2.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

# Pack the canvases after the scrollbar
canvas1.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)
canvas2.pack(side=LEFT, fill=BOTH, expand=True)

# This is the updated even handler:
def _on_mousewheel(event):
    event.widget.yview_scroll(int(-1*(event.delta/120)), "units")

# Bind mousewheel to scrollbars
canvas1.bind("<MouseWheel>", _on_mousewheel)
canvas2.bind("<MouseWheel>", _on_mousewheel)

# Configure the canvases scrollbars
canvas1.configure(scrollregion=canvas1.bbox('all'), yscrollcommand=scrollbar1.set)
canvas1.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas1.configure(scrollregion = canvas1.bbox("all")))
canvas2.configure(scrollregion=canvas2.bbox('all'), yscrollcommand=scrollbar2.set)
canvas2.bind('<Configure>', lambda e: canvas2.configure(scrollregion = canvas2.bbox("all")))

# Create frames inside the canvases
inner_frame1 = ttk.Frame(canvas1)
inner_frame2 = ttk.Frame(canvas2)

# Add the frames to the canvases
canvas1.create_window((0,0), window=inner_frame1, anchor="nw")
canvas2.create_window((0,0), window=inner_frame2, anchor="nw")

# Add buttons to the frames
for thing in range(20):
    ttk.Button(inner_frame1, text=f'Button {thing}').grid(row=thing, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)
    ttk.Button(inner_frame2, text=f'Button {thing}').grid(row=thing, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)

Window.mainloop()
```

My guess is that when you first pack the canvas with `expand=True, fill="both"`, it decided that it will try to take as much space as possible without thinking about the scrollbar. I don't really know why that happens.

Comment: Awesome!  That works perfectly.  Any ideas on the weird behavior of the scrollbar disappearing if you resize the window to make it narrower?

Comment: @tehruttiger got it I will update my answer.

Comment: Your guess is more-or-less correct. The order in which you call `pack` affects which widgets get reduced when all of the widgets won't fit. By packing the canvas last, that's the one that gets reduced when they don't all fit.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for the clarification. I usually use `grid` and rarely use `pack` so I don't fully know how it works.

Comment: I always use .grid but thought I had to use pack for the canvases and scrollbars.  How would I use grid to ensure its always on the very far right?

Comment: Looks like I need to make use of sticky and potentially rowspan (for vertical).  Seems easy enough.  Thanks for you help!